# Removing markers from Biostall Google Maps for CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps

I am using the Biostall Google Maps for Codeigniter and got it fully installed. But I want to remove some markers with ajax and the js code it executes is this:

```
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.236114, 6.496444);

        var markerOptions = {
            map: map,
            position: myLatlng      
        };
        marker_16 = createMarker_map(markerOptions);
```

16 in "marker_16" is the id of the marker. I want to be able to delete the marker by the id. How would I do this with Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using my library. To remove a particular marker try:

```
marker_16.setMap(null);
```

That should (fingers crossed) work for you. Hope that helps!

Comment: Your library is great and I tried to use your solution before but it doesn't work for clusters. So I used this: markerCluster.removeMarker(marker_16);markerCluster.redraw(); Which works like a charm!